# How to read from /dev/random?

Tags: import, files-and-directories, mac-os-x, streams

I am looking to read a few bytes from `/dev/random` on OS X and Linux.  The simplest approach fails on both operating systems (see below).

Why?  What is a workaround?

```
In[1]:= random = OpenRead["/dev/random"]

During evaluation of In[1]:= OpenRead::noopen: Cannot open /dev/random. >>

Out[1]= $Failed

In[2]:= BinaryRead["/dev/random", "Integer32"]

During evaluation of In[2]:= BinaryRead::nffil: File not found during BinaryRead[/dev/random,Integer32]. >>

Out[2]= $Failed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One workaround I found is this:

```
getRand[] :=
 AbortProtect@Module[{stream, res},
   stream = OpenRead["!head -c 4 /dev/random", BinaryFormat -> True];
   res = BinaryRead[stream, "UnsignedInteger32"];
   Close[stream];
   res
 ]
```

Tested on OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

read *n* bytes from `/dev/urandom` and return a `ByteArray`:

```
getrnd[n_Integer /; n >= 1] := 
    ReadByteArray["!dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 bs=" <> ToString[n]]
```